# "if (location.href != example.com/page1 || example.com/page2)" Change CSS element

Tags: javascript, html, css, location, location-href

When I use these similar JS code (the 2 immediately below), my output is wrong or doesn't show.
Here is my codes in question:

```
if (location.href != "website.com/page1" || "website.com/page2")
   {
     element.style.backgroundColor='none';
   }
```

or with != and !==

```
if (location.href != "website.com/page1" || location.href != "website.com/page2")
   {
     element.style.backgroundColor='none';
   }
```

Here is how I'm using it with other code (simplified)

```
<script>
var element = document.getElementbyId('idElement');

if (location.href != "website.com/page1")
   {
     element.style.backgroundColor='blue';
   }
if (location.href != "website.com/page2")
   {
     element.style.backgroundColor='green';
   }
 //HERE'S WHERE I PUT IT
if (location.href != "website.com/page1" || "website.com/page2")
   {
     element.style.backgroundColor='none';
   }
 </script>
```

Either nothing happens or the element doesn't work properly on other pages.

What am I doing wrong?

More Info: I'm making a Tumblr theme and there are pages that will have certain post with different characteristics when viewed on different pages. I have to have this code in the top.

Someone Suggested This: SOLVED

```
<script>
     window.onload = function ()

 var element = document.getElementbyId('idElement');

 if (location.href != "website.com/page1" && location.href != "website.com/page2") 
    {
       element.style.backgroundColor='none'; 
    } 
  if (location.href == "website.com/page1") 
    {
       element.style.backgroundColor='blue'; 
    }
  if (location.href == "website.com/page2") 
        { 
       element.style.backgroundColor='green'; 
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Use location.pathname - location.href includes the domain

Comment: A pair of inequality comparisons like that, separated by a logical "or", will **always** be true.

Comment: The problem is in the logic of the if statements. The 3rd `if` (the code in question) is never hit because if the `href` is page1, it hits the 2nd `if`, and if the `href` is page2 it hits the 1st `if`, and if its anything else it will always hit the 1st `if`. You need to make them `if/else if/else` statements to get the correct output and put the 3rd `if` as the first if statement, followed by the other two.

Comment: How would you do that @straker?

Comment: I see your code change, sorry I didn't make my suggestion clear enough. What I mean to say was do this:

     `var element = document.getElementbyId('idElement');

      if (location.href != "website.com/page1" || location.href != "website.com/page2")
      {
        element.style.backgroundColor='none';
      }
      else if (location.href != "website.com/page1")
      {
        element.style.backgroundColor='blue';
      }
      else {
        element.style.backgroundColor='green';
      }`

Apparently you can't add code very easily in comments...

Comment: Also, you should make the `||` into `&&`, as stated earlier, the `||` will always be true.

Comment: Thanks @straker! I solved it. I used if statements instead of if-else.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from obvious syntactic error (for example, you left off a closing quotation mark after website.com/page2), there are a few things you might want to do, to narrow this down a bit.

For one thing, you might want to only get the location.href once and store that in a variable. While you're doing that, you could use toLowerCase() on it, so that you know for certain you're comparing apples to apples:

```
var currLoc = location.href.toLowerCase();
```

Your logic is also a bit interesting... first you're saying, "If we're not on page1, use blue. If we're not on page2, use green. If we're not on page1 or string is page2, use no color."

So, at the end of it all, no color is showing up because the very last thing you're saying is to clear the color if you're not on page1 or page2? That part is not terribly clear and is probably part of the problem, in addition to the syntax errors. Note that, when evaluating this line:

```
if (location.href != "website.com/page1" || "website.com/page2)
```

you're saying "if location.href isn't page1 OR if String("website.com/page2") exists"

If you're testing location.href in both cases, you want:

```
if (location.href != "website.com/page1" && location.href != "website.com/page2")
```

as I assume what you mean to say.

So, try changing your script to something like this:

```
var element = document.getElementbyId('idElement');
var currLoc = location.href.toLowerCase();

// let's save this in a var, too, so you're only changing color once!
var toColor = "none"; 

if (currLoc != "website.com/page1") {
    toColor = 'blue';
}
if (currLoc != "website.com/page2") {
    toColor = 'green';
}
//HERE'S WHERE I PUT IT
if (currLoc != "website.com/page1" && currLoc != "website.com/page2") {
    toColor = 'none';
}

element.style.backgroundColor = toColor;
```

Comment: megawac made a good observation as well in his comment... if those strings that you're comparing against don't need to include the domain name, then use `location.pathname.toLowerCase()` and leave out the domain name from the comparison-strings.

Answer (score 0):

You're not closing your if statements properly.

This:

```
if (location.href != "website.com/page1" || "website.com/page2)
```

Should look like this:

```
if (location.href != "website.com/page1" || "website.com/page2")
```

and this:

```
if (location.href != "website.com/page1" || location.href != "website.com/page2)
```

Should look like this:

```
if (location.href != "website.com/page1" || location.href != "website.com/page2")
```

If it still doesn't work, I suggest doing this at the top of your function.

```
alert(location.href);
```

and seeing what location.href actually equals.

**edit**

Now instead of this:

```
(location.href != "website.com/page1" || "website.com/page2")
```

It needs to look like this:

```
(location.href != "website.com/page1" || location.href != "website.com/page2")
```

We're slowly getting there!

Comment: `location.href != "website.com/page1" || "website.com/page2` -- this only checks page2

Comment: Note that the first if statement is malformed in another way, see my explanation below... as written, it would always evaluate true.

Comment: the missing parentheses was fixed for the question. I needed to make to make sure how to change the css on pages that weren't page1 or page 2.